# When targeting a Picture element in CSS, should we use img or picture selector?

Tags: css, html, image

So the new Picture element looks like this:

```
<picture>
  <source ... />
  <img browsers will fall back to this width="10" height="10" />
</picture>
```

In our CSS, we want to set say a background color.

```
picture {background-color: red};
img {background-color: yellow};
```

Will a Picture enabled browser just show a red background, while non enabled browsers show a yellow background? Or a combination of the two.  Likewise, will an Picture enabled browser see the height/width attributes on the img element, or is the img element ignored completly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea of the picture element is that that it simply provides source information for its enclosed img element, and that it is always the img element that is rendered, not the picture element.

However, I can't see anything normative in the spec that suggests that the picture element will be treated by default as anything other than an inline element, so I expect that you will be able to style it with a different `display` setting, give it padding etc., in the same way as you can do with `span` elements, in which case, the background-color will behave in the same way as a span element around an img element does today.

So targeting both might be appropriate. The backgrounds will simply layer as normal. But the img will be rendered, so in your scenario, the background behind the image will be yellow, assuming of course that the img has at least some degree of transparency.

Comment: Interesting, so the picture/source elements are more of a syntax to modify the src attribute of it's image rather than being renderable elements themselves. So <picture> supporting browsers don't ignore the img, they just modify it. Meaning it's still correct to target the img element with CSS. Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: I saw multiple blog and SO posts saying that styles on img tags and picture tags behave in the same way. Often, this is true. It is, however, important to know that applying certain styles to the img tag will have a different effect than applying it to the picture tag. Things like width will have different results.

Comment: @StefanTeunissen - Yes. Put simply, those blogs and posts are _wrong_. img and picture elements are completely different concepts, and generate separate CSS boxes which can be styled independently.

Answer (score 0):

Since no browser supports it, guess we'll need to wait to see the implementation, but by the looks of it so far, and according to current docs, it seems img tag will be completely ignored and only used as fallback.

The new implementation is as follows:

```
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 64em)" src="high-res.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width: 37.5em)" src="med-res.jpg">
   <source src="low-res.jpg">
   <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="This picture loads on non-supporting browsers.">
   <p>Accessible text.</p>
</picture>
```

since you'll need to define the images inside `<picture>` element as sources and you won't have an img tag, implementation in browsers with Picture implementation shouldn't recognize anything inside an img tag unless the media src isn't defined.

However, it's easy to see this approach will cause a double download of images since browsers download all `<img>` tags first. Because of this, there's a [proposal by David Newton](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/10/how-to-avoid-duplicate-downloads-in-responsive-images/): to use `<object>` or `<embed>` as fallback image containers to avoid duplication of images being downloaded.

All the above being said, we just need to wait, but in short, my answer is  that your first option `picture {background-color: red};` is the correct one

Comment: There is no danger of a double download because it is the img element whose source is downloaded. The picture element just modifies the source that the img element uses. That's why the source elements must precede the img element within the picture element.

Comment: it will be like you say in certain situations if you don't care about responsive behaviors and use only one image just like you say. But the whole idea behind the `<picture>` element is using it for responsive layouts. See my example code: you'll download high-res.jpg, mid-res.jpg and low-res.jpg, then fallback.jpg. Granted that you could use, instead of fallback, high-res.jpg to be sure to cover all sizes. In this case, you don't even need the `<picture>` element. If you use mid-res.jpg as fallback, your image will look awful on big screens.

Comment: (continues) So if you comply with the responsive approach, then you'll need all 3 images and a fallback that may (or may not) be one of those 3 images. So it's really easy to see that at least in 2 sizes, you'll have a double download for each `<picture>` element in your page

Comment: In a responsive  scenario, the page author needs to account for each possible set of screen characteristics. But the browser doesn't, it knows what screen characteristics it has got. So it can just download the correct image for those characteristics. It doesn't need the others. I can see situations where a mobile phone or tablet might predictively download the image for the "other" screen orientation if rotation would cause the changed characteristics to cross a break point, but otherwise it wouldn't download a second image unless those screen characteristics actually changed.